# What IAM role is needed to deploy `cron.yaml`?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am attempting to deploy a `cron.yaml` file with `gcloud app deploy` with a service account that has the "GAE admin" role on my project.

It is apparently not sufficient to update my cron config. It seems I need to give the service account the "project editor" role to continue.

The error I got was:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
  Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
  You do not have permission to modify this app
```

Is there a way to update `cron.yaml` without requiring the "project editor" role.

Answer (score 7):

As documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/granting-project-access#deploying_using_iam_roles), to deploy `cron.yaml`, you need the "Cloud Scheduler > Cloud Scheduler Admin role".

Comment: Hi Steren, the cron jobs are deployed on google cloud but the functions are deployed on firebase function, if i am correct. In order to execute this command 
 `gcloud app deploy app.yaml cron.yaml` you also need the admin permission on firebase to perform the `cron.yaml` deployment on google cloud and functions on firebase. Am I correct ?

Comment: Thanks. You can run this command to add the role to your cloudbuild service account: gcloud --project $(PROJECT_ID) projects add-iam-policy-binding $(PROJECT_ID) --member=serviceAccount:$(PROJECT_NUMBER)@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/cloudscheduler.admin